# didReceiveMemoryWarning using a Tab Bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, didreceivememorywarning, viewdidunload

I have a `UITabBar` holding `3 UIViewControllers`.
One being a map, the other - a table, and the third - my own custom controller.
I noticed lately that my app has some issues when it comes to operating on low memory, and it's due to me not being clear about what to do when `didReceiveMemoryWarning` occurs.

Usually, and when with sufficient memory, all functions great. I would alloc all my controllers on the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and all controllers work great.

But what happens when the memory is a bit low is that (for some reason) only my table is misbehaving. 
First, I can see that the app received a memory warning. and then only my table gets a `viewDidUnload`.
At first I wasn't sure why my table became **`*completely empty*`**, but then I realized that my delegation methods stopped working rendering my `reloadData` essentially pointless.

So, I can see now that the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is cascading through all my viewControllers. But viewDidUnload is called only on my table.

I want to know what is going on?

- How do I recover from a viewDidUnload? If my view is nil, who is responsible for bringing it back?
  Why is it that only my table is getting the viewDidUnload? I was reading [this link](http://the.ichibod.com/kiji/uiviewcontroller-memory-management-methods/) and [that one](http://blog.lukhnos.org/post/101548146/iphone-view-controller-memory-management-in-a-nutshell), and some of apples documentation but found no explanation to why my view doesn't recover.

What should I be doing in this case?

Comment: First of all, you should figure out why your app is using so much memory. What version of iOS are you using? In iOS 6, viewDidUnload is no longer called.

Comment: The program is designed to support iOS 4.3. @rdelmar, once the user has pressed each button on the tab bar, the views persists. Meaning that a view is in memory as long as the app is running (there are only three). Is this acceptable?

Comment: Three controllers certainly shouldn't be enough to cause a memory warning. What do you have in them? Are you using a lot of images or sounds? If not, then you must have a memory leak.

Comment: I saw in the profiler that the memory usage keeps going up. very slowly. utilizing around 70-80 megabytes. Obviously I must attend to that. Still, why would my table get unloaded and never loads again?